# Python Thread : TypeError: __main__.generate_num() argument after * must be an iterable, not Event

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am experiment the Threads with Event

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import queue
import random

def generate_num(e):
    print('e',e.is_set())
    while True:
        if e.is_set():
            print('g', random.randint(15, 20))
        else:
            print('g', 0)
    
def start_generating():
    i = 0
    e = Event()
    r_thread = Thread(target=generate_num, args=(e), daemon=True).start()
    print('starting')

    while True:
        print('i', i)
        if i %5 == 0:
            e.set()
        if i ==12:
            exit(0)
        i+=1

start_generating()
```

My aim is that when `i` becomes 5 or 10, it should print the random number, otherwise it should print `0`.

But, I got this error

```
starting
i 0
i 1
i 2
Exception in thread Thread-6 (generate_num):
Traceback (most recent call last):
i 3
i 4
i 5
i 6
i 7
i 8
i 9
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    i 10
iself.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
11
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: __main__.generate_num() argument after * must be an iterable, not Event
i 12
```

How to solve this, thanks

Comment: The *args* keyword requires an iterable. *args=(e,)* will solve that problem. Also worth noting that there's no need to pass the event to the thread as it could be made available in the global address space

Comment: @DarkKnight, There's also no need to make the `event` global  when it can be passed as an argument. But, using globals is a dirty habit. IMO, Vishak made the better choice here.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Please re-read my comment. I said "could" not "should".

Comment: @DarkKnight, Me too! I said, "can," not "must."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments and also in the error the `args` are not an iterable or to be more specific a tuple, which is what the args argument normally should be.

Creating a tuple with only one element needs a trailing `,`

```py
one_element_tuple = (1,)
```

So just do

```py
from threading import Thread, Event
import queue
import random

def generate_num(e):
    print('e',e.is_set())
    while True:
        if e.is_set():
            print('g', random.randint(15, 20))
        else:
            print('g', 0)
    
def start_generating():
    i = 0
    e = Event()
    r_thread = Thread(target=generate_num, args=(e,), daemon=True).start()
    print('starting')

    while True:
        print('i', i)
        if i %5 == 0:
            e.set()
        if i ==12:
            exit(0)
        i+=1

start_generating()
```

Comment: Why do you say that the iterable assigned to *args* would "normally" be a tuple?

Comment: I just want to emphasize that the standard is to use a `tuple` but in theory this function does not care about the specific type as long as it is an iterable. So one could use a `list` or even a  `set`. That is why the error says iterable. In the end all does inside is to call the target function and use the `*` operator to pass the args to it e.g. `f(*args)` and the `*` operator just extracts all elements from an iterable and passes them as individually values to the function.

Comment: I don't see any reference to this in "the standard". Please enlighten us

Comment: I am just referring to what is commonly done and that one should use a tuple if there is no reason not to.